# Laravel Seeding error SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

When I'm trying to seed my database, but I get an error saying that I have a duplicate entry '1' for the key 'users_class_id_unique.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

This is what the error looks like

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' 
for key 'users_class_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, 
`lastname`, `email`, `class_id`, `password`
`role_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (Example, Name, 
example@outlook.com, 1, 
$2y$10$gqFXkYt9LRoCH6LqsosEPOI/2t.VDoNzBgV3x/przh.1KiuJqvRwe, 2, 1971-06-20 
06:10:44, 1975-03-0
9 17:46:23))



[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' 
for key 'users_class_id_unique'
```

This is my seeder file

```
<?php

use Faker\Factory;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    //Zeker weten dat de eerste user één admin is
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Rainier',
        'lastname' => 'Laan',
        'email' => 'rainier.laan@home.nl',
        'class_id' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Collin',
        'lastname' => 'Nieuw Beerta',
        'email' => 'collinweetnietwelkeemail@hotmail.com',
        'class_id' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 1,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Godpieter',
        'lastname' => 'alwin',
        'email' => 'Godpieter@Allmightygodpieter.com',
        'class_id' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    // Onderste code maakt 8 random users aan met het wachtwoord 'Welkom'

    foreach(range(1,7) as $index) {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'class_id' => rand(1, 3),
            'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
            'role_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
            'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

Class MODEL

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Classes extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'class_name', 'subject_id',
];

public function subjects() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}


}
```

CLASS Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateClassesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('subject_id');
        $table->string('class_name')->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
}
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `class_id` to be `unique`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can not insert 'class_id' => 1 for both users . This class id should be unique .
And it's defined in your model file .
If you want to insert same 'class_id' then change your model and db OR other-wise change your 'class_id' one of them .
Such as: 
'class_id' => 1,
'class_id' => 2,

```
<?php

use Faker\Factory;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    //Zeker weten dat de eerste user één admin is
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Rainier',
        'lastname' => 'Laan',
        'email' => 'rainier.laan@home.nl',
        'class_id' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Collin',
        'lastname' => 'Nieuw Beerta',
        'email' => 'collinweetnietwelkeemail@hotmail.com',
        'class_id' => 2,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 1,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Godpieter',
        'lastname' => 'alwin',
        'email' => 'Godpieter@Allmightygodpieter.com',
        'class_id' => 3,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    // Onderste code maakt 8 random users aan met het wachtwoord 'Welkom'

    foreach(range(4,10) as $index) {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'class_id' => rand(1, 3),
            'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
            'role_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
            'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the class Migration and model. I don't quite understand what you just said. Maybe you can tell me what to do with those files? to make it work?

Comment: check your database at users table : your class_id column set unique ... change it .
Can you provide your user migration ?

Comment: I indeed set my Class_id to unique in the Users migration, But it shouldn't be?

Comment: it should .... check my edited answer ... delete rows from users table and run again this seed .

Comment: Now it gets the first 3 users but not the 7 random generated ones and gives me the error again

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 check my answer. The reason it does is because class_id gets set to a non-unique value through the random function.

Comment: The class ID needs to be either 1 2 or 3. Nothing more than those numbers, so every user needs to be assigned to a class id with either 1, 2 or 3. So it needs to be unique right?

Comment: yes ... any number but unique for every rows ... that's right .

Comment: I changed it to not unique and now it works and everything is filled with fake data but my users table is gone, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays inside your migration. Your column `class_id` is set to unique but you keep assigning the same value `'class_id' => 1`. Change it to

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('subject_id');
        $table->string('class_name');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and re-run the migrations. Also make sure that it gets changed in the users table.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

You will have to figure out yourself whether you need the column to be unique or not. If it has to be unique, you will have to change the seeder to make sure it only seeds unique values for `class_id`.

If you cannot re-run the migrations, change the seeder like this:

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    //Zeker weten dat de eerste user één admin is
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Rainier',
        'lastname' => 'Laan',
        'email' => 'rainier.laan@home.nl',
        'class_id' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Collin',
        'lastname' => 'Nieuw Beerta',
        'email' => 'collinweetnietwelkeemail@hotmail.com',
        'class_id' => 2,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 1,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'Godpieter',
        'lastname' => 'alwin',
        'email' => 'Godpieter@Allmightygodpieter.com',
        'class_id' => 3,
        'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
        'role_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ]);

    // Onderste code maakt 8 random users aan met het wachtwoord 'Welkom'

    foreach(range(4,10) as $index) {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'class_id' => $index,
            'password' => bcrypt('welkom'),
            'role_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
            'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In case your `class_id` needs to be either 1, 2 or 3, then use your seeder.